# How to make logrotate to copytruncate the original file only after a newline

Tags: logrotate

I am trying to logrotate every 15 minutes a CDR file consisting of multiple CDR records, where each CDR record is present in a new line, all works fine but logrotate truncates the file in the middle of last CDR record which results in breaking latest CDR record across 2 files.

Is there a way/option to tell logrotate to only truncate the file after it sees the newline character so that no CDR record is truncated in the middle?

Thanks

Comment: You might add your `logrotate` configuration related to this file, so that everyone can see what is happening.

Comment: /traces/CDRs/cdr.txt {
 missingok
 rotate 1
 size=50M
 copytruncate
 compress
 postrotate
  /traces/CDRs/rename.sh & 
 endscript
}